# Does the noexec mount option imply nosuid?

Tags: mount, executable, setuid

Many guides on the internet recommend setting the nosuid **and** noexec options, for example on the /tmp mount point. But doesn't noexec imply nosuid? What cannot get executed cannot make use of the suid bit, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://superuser.com/questions/532667/why-the-need-to-mount-a-partition-with-nosuid-when-noexec-is-present
It looks like 'nosuid' is basically recommended universally in case you might be using a kernel that allows noexec to be circumvented.

Comment: The suid bit is not only useful for exec files.

Comment: the setgid bit on directories seems to work fine even with `nosuid`.  `mount(2)` says "MS_NOSUID: Do not honor set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits when executing programs from this filesystem."

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro What else do you think it's useful for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the link LJKims, it helps me to answer my own question. I forgot that the suid/sgid bit can also be set for directories.

According to [the GNU coreutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) files and directories that are created in a suid-directory inherit the owner of the directory (sgid-directories inherit the group obviously). So, if you want to avoid this behaviour, **setting both noexec and nosuid on a mount point makes sense**.

For completeness: in my tests on a current Debian, the suid bit on directories takes no effect, but only the sgid bit makes files/directories inherit the group of the directory.

```
# mkdir /test
# chmod 6777 /test
# ls -ld /test
drwsrwsrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun 10 18:50 /test
$ mkdir /test/foo; touch /test/bar
$ ls -l /test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    0 Jun 10 18:51 bar
drwxr-sr-x 2 user root 4096 Jun 10 18:51 foo
```

**Edit:**
For completeness: The nosuid mount option does not affect sgid-directories (on Debian 8 at least).

```
# mount -o loop,nosuid test.img /test
# mkdir /test/foo
# chmod 2777 /test/foo
$ touch /test/foo/bar; mkdir /test/foo/baz
$ ls -l /test/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    0 Jun 12 09:46 bar
drwxr-sr-x 2 user root 4096 Jun 12 09:46 baz
```

Comment: But AFAICT the nosuid option has no effect on the sgid behaviour of directories (the files created in sgid directories still inherit the group of the directory).

Comment: That's right, see my edit. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: But then that doesn't explain why combining nosuid with noexec makes any difference.

Comment: Well, if the distribution pays respect to the suid bit on directories, then it makes a difference.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. the `nosuid` flag makes no different wrt the behaviour of the suid/sgid bits on directories. So far, we've only ascertained that it has an effect on the `execve()` system call, but with `noexec`, `execve()` will refuse to execute the files anyway regardless of the permission bits.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Note that it's Linux kernel behaviour, it's independent of the distribution, that behaviour is not configurable without modifying the kernel source code.